# Limit property for 4 sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_n, (b_n)_n, (c_n)_n$ and $(d_n)_n$ be four real-valued sequences such that
$$ a_n = b_n + c_n -d_n \qquad \mbox{ for all } n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Suppose that $a_n\longrightarrow 0$ and $d_n\longrightarrow 0$ as $n\to +\infty$. It always implies that
$$(b_n + c_n)_n\longrightarrow 0 \quad \mbox{ as } n\to +\infty?$$
Or not? Could anyone help me to understand?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rephrased:

$a_n=b_n+c_n;$

Given that $a_n$, $c_n \rightarrow 0$ does it follow

$b_n \rightarrow 0$?

$b_n= (b_n+c_n)- c_n=a_n-c_n;$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_n-c_n)=$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n -\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}c_n=0$;

Note: Since both limits exist the limit of the sum (difference) equals the sum (diff.) of the limits.

Thus

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_n-c_n)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

Yes,$$(b_n + c_n)_n\longrightarrow 0 \quad \mbox{ as } n\to +\infty.$$Because $b_n+c_n=a_n+d_n,$we just need to prove $a_n+d_n\rightarrow 0.$In fact, for any given $\epsilon>0,$there exist $N_1,N_2$ such that for any $n>N_1,m>N_2$$$|a_n-0|\le \epsilon/2,|d_n-0|\le \epsilon/2.$$Hence for any $n> \max(N_1,N_2)$$$|a_n+d_n|\le |a_n|+|d_n|\le \epsilon.$$So by definition of convergence, $a_n+d_n \rightarrow 0,$so $$(b_n + c_n)_n \rightarrow 0 \quad \mbox{ as } n\to +\infty$$